# Issue with json loads

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Lets say I have a below file:

```
{"id":"3234", "brand": "xyz", "binary":"fdsjl2j3jrl90i0ife"}
{"id":"4332", "brand": "abc", "binary":"hshgfdgfdsl90i0fsf"}
{"id":"2542", "brand": "wtr", "binary":"gfdgf22332l90i0ife"}
{"id":"9922", "brand": "kjl", "binary":"fdsjl23gssdsfwe223"}
```

When I run the below function:

```
import json

filename = 'udata'
filename2 = 'odata'

#initialize list
records = []

#add records from the file to the list
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(json.loads(line))
```

records returns data with single quotation('') instead of ""

```
{'id': '2542', 'brand': 'wtr', 'binary': 'gfdgf22332l90i0ife'}
{'id': '3234', 'brand': 'xyz', 'binary': 'fdsjl2j3jrl90i0ife'}
{'id': '4332', 'brand': 'abc', 'binary': 'hshgfdgfdsl90i0fsf'}
{'id': '9922', 'brand': 'kjl', 'binary': 'fdsjl23gssdsfwe223'}
```

Wanted output:

```
{"id":"3234", "brand": "xyz", "binary":"fdsjl2j3jrl90i0ife"}
{"id":"4332", "brand": "abc", "binary":"hshgfdgfdsl90i0fsf"}
{"id":"2542", "brand": "wtr", "binary":"gfdgf22332l90i0ife"}
{"id":"9922", "brand": "kjl", "binary":"fdsjl23gssdsfwe223"}
```

Comment: Those mean the same thing in Python. If you just wanted to print out JSON unchanged, why did you deserialize it to a dict? `print(line)`

Comment: I'm not sure what your "issue" is. You're not using json.dumps in this code, you're using json.loads; after which it displays the Python data structure correctly. What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: The dicts simply contain strings, which do not have embedded quotes. There is no way to force python to display strings with a specific quote character. Why do you care about this?

Comment: records is empty list, you do not add anything to it, why you think it returns something except `[]`?

Comment: I wanted to sort them using id and output to a file without using pandas

Comment: Then you’ll need to use `json.dumps` again when performing output.

Answer (score 0):

That's really not a problem. They mean the exact same thing.